# Linq-to-SQL Database DataContext seems to populate table automatically

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, mvvm, linq-to-sql

I have a seemingly odd issue here. I'm new to Linq-to-SQL, so I might be missing something obvious.

I have a DataContext dbml representing the tables in my database, and one of these tables represents a log table which accumulates a lot of records. Simply adding this table to the dbml appears to populate every record from the database into the DataContext object (and therefore my viewmodel, since the datacontext is a member of the viewmodel).

I never noticed this until I serialized the viewmodel into XML and noticed the file size was rather large for the data contained in the viewmodel.

Opening up the XML revealed every single log record from this table was present, despite not being referenced anywhere except the initialization of the Linq-to-SQL datacontext object (table is not referenced).

I haven't yet checked if other tables are doing the same thing (other tables are very small since this project and database is still new), but the log table stood out as 80% of the size of the serialized file.

This is also worrying, since it is being queried and stored in memory, costing me additional performance. This will be a big problem once the software is in use and the database grows at a large rate.

Any ideas on to how to prevent Linq-to-SQL from pulling in every record? Thanks.

Comment: Why is the DataContext in the ViewModel? If you serialize it, it will serialize every public member including every table. You should never put the DataContext in a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Sql relies heavily on deferred execution.  So, while the DataContext may have, for example, a Logs property, it doesn't contain all the log records from your database.

You can interact with the property, but it *still* doesn't necessarily mean anything has happened.

```
var myLogs = context.logs.Where(x => x.UserName = "lol");
```

This *still* hasn't done anything.  Linq to Sql uses IQueryables to define what you wish to get from the database without actually proactively going to get them.  It's only when you do something to the IQueryable that the results are returned from the database.

```
foreach(var log in myLogs) Console.WriteLine(log);
```

So, what does this have to do with your situation?  You see, the serializer doesn't know jack about this.  It just sees an object with a bunch of properties.

So, when it's serializing the object, it **enumerates through the property values** and writes them to xml.  Thus, all the data from your database is pulled out by this action.

There are lots of side effects when dealing with IQueryables which you should be aware of before using them.  You might find yourself serializing the entire database, as in this case, or you might DDOS your db server by working with an IQueryable in a loop rather than pulling the data into memory once and working on it there.

The solution in your case is not to serialize the context.  Either null it out prior or mark it with an attribute that it shouldn't be serialized.

Comment: The DataContext itself is not set as a property, and such shouldn't be serialized. However, my viewmodel contains some sub-viewmodels that have properties that **get** their data from a Linq-to-SQL DataContext. For example, my main ViewModel's properties are something like: public int ID { get { return id; } set { id = value; **DataContext**.id = value; } }, but some of the sub-viewmodels have properties such as: public string X { get { return **DataContext**.X; } set { **DataContext**.X = value; } }. Could the getters on these sub-viewmodel properties be causing the problem?

Comment: @user5269172 the serializer has got a hold of an object which can be traced back to the context via publicly available references.

Comment: Thanks for the fast update, is it bad practice in MVVM to have getters reference Linq-to-SQL DataContext table values as opposed to local fields? Some of my models are "wrappers" around DataContext table objects, for futher customization and calculated values.

Comment: @user5269172 not necessarily bad, unless you're facing issues like this.  I don't prefer ORMs like this as you have to worry about mapping back and forth to entities.  Lots of wasted flapping about :/